# Oracle Cursor expression vs standard join

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to understand what is so
Special about cursor expressions, when effectively you could do this with a straight sub query?

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions005.htm

Answer (score 2):

A `CURSOR` is effectively a pointer to an area of memory on the database server so, instead of passing a result set containing all the data contained in a collection (nested table) or `VARRAY` or of performing a `JOIN` and returning multiple rows, you can return a single pointer and then the client application has the option of retrieving that cursor or not as required.

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       CURSOR( SELECT child FROM child_table c WHERE p.id = c.parent_id )
         AS children
FROM   parent_table p
```

Compared to:

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       ( SELECT CAST( COLLECT( child ) AS some_collection_type )
         FROM   child_table c
         WHERE  p.id = c.parent_id
       ) AS children
FROM   parent_table p
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       child
FROM   parent_table p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN child_table c
       ON (p.id = c.parent_id)
```

With the `CURSOR` expression, you can are initially passed the pointers (`CURSOR`) and not the data and can chose to retrieve those cursor(s) you are interested and do not need to retrieve the values for the uninteresting rows; with the other options, you have to retrieve all the child data with the rest of the row.

Comment: Thanks.  So it’s only really for using in client applications which are using a driver which supports cursor retrieval?

Comment: @smackenzie You can use it in PL/SQL and parse the cursors in any application [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=46478baf1cfeb3e0079e1589e2c0da98). However, I'm guessing the main use is in client applications to minimise the initial load but its not a commonly used feature.